# Electron framework and privacy

Tags: electron, chromium, privacy

I'm considering developing a cross platform Electron app.

According to the [Electron website](https://electronjs.org/), Electron uses Chromium, the open-source version of Google's Chrome browser. However, given the [privacy concerns regarding Google](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_and_privacy_issues) and [Chromium](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/144289/privacy-with-chromium) and [Electron's implicit use of Google services](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/7306), I wonder if using a Chromium-based platform would be a good idea.

The eventual app will need to be as secure and private as possible, as it might be used to process sensitive data provided by the user.

Do Electron and/or its Chromium components track users in any way? Do they make any Internet connections by themselves? Do they collect and send data to third parties? Is it possible to run Electron while offline (see [these reports](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/6437))? Is the Electron framework appropriate for designing privacy-focused apps?

Comment: Electron uses Chromium rendering engine ie Blink and V8. It doesn't include the Chromium browser. So in other words, it doesn't track users or send data to third parties. To answer your second question: the source code of Electron based apps can be easily extracted, as all your files will be stored in an ASAR archive.

Comment: Just because Electron does not include the *full* Chromium browser doesn't mean that it doesn't track users or send data to third parties. Regarding your second point, it is clear that app code can introduce all sorts of issues. The question is whether the framework itself is appropriate for designing privacy-focused apps.

Comment: @lecodesportif Chromium developer here. Like I said earlier, it's the Chromium browser which does that. Also in Chromium browser most of those will be disabled, but only enabled in Chrome.

Answer (score 10):

Electron does not track your users, it uses mainly the [Content Module](https://www.chromium.org/developers/content-module) for rendering HTML/CSS and executing JS and a set of chromium features, anything telemetry/privacy related only gets executed when you also provide a google API key, and at the moment [that is only for the "geolocation" API](https://github.com/electron/electron/search?q=GOOGLE_API_KEY&unscoped_q=GOOGLE_API_KEY).

The good thing is you can search the whole codebase, there is nothing from electron itself that could be a concern for privacy, except you add a Google API key.

But that does not include stuff you add to the app later on, if you start loading external web pages like a browser, you're defenseless agains them tracking your users.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Chromium will track internet events of users and send them to third-party. You can monitor the Network tab on Electron app (maybe they can hide the information) or use some tools for tracking the internet request when building Electron app. 
Another point that you should know that many enterprise applications such as Skype, Slack... are based on Electron.